# codeigniter upload function not uploading to directory

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've followed the codeigniter example when it comes to uploading a file, but for some reason it is not working. I've created the folder uploads under public_html folder immediately. I've checked also the flow of the code using echo statements, and it is reaching within the if statement shown below, yet still nothing is showing in the directory uploads which is set to permission 0777.

```
if($_FILES)
                {
                    //handling the upload
                    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                    $config['max_size'] = '100';
                    $config['max_width']  = '480';
                    $config['max_height']  = '270';
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                    if ( ! $this->courseImage())
                    {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        $this->load->view('new/image', $error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                        $this->load->view('error', $data);
                    }

                }else{
                    $this->load->view('new/image');
                }
```

Appreciate your support and I am still learning codeigniter, so forgive me if it is too easy of a problem.

Comment: Your not calling `$this->upload->do_upload()` anywhere in the above code, if its in `$this->courseImage()` you need to show that too.

Comment: change the upload path to /uploads. lose the . and the trailing slash and see if that works, if you aren't getting the error page the file should be uploading, just likely to a directory you aren't expecting it to

Comment: @Re0sless it is courseImage instead. I believe this is a recursive call because I am calling a function within a function. Rick, no it didn't work. Still does the same thing. It takes  a little time and then reload the same upload page again.Nothing uploaded

Answer (score 0):

I did something else and this worked for me. I followed the exact function names provided in codeigniter docs and it worked. I created a method called do_upload and called it using $this->do_upload. This actually worked well.

Thanks